# How do I reset my directory structure and contents?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, unix, mount

I have a linux box in the cloud and it had this directory structure

`/mnt/ws/{myProjects}`

I was trying to mount a (directory I believe?) from another resource and I did it through the following command.

`mount -t cifs -o user=admin,password=123,ro //199.1.1.1/somepkg /mnt`

(fake credentials)

Now my directory structure is like this

`/mnt/ws/folder`

and basically I can't find the other files I had.

I am trying to reset this and a bit confused as to what happened. Is there an easy way to get my directory back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simple: umount your CIFS filesystem `umount /mnt`

What you did was mount the CIFS filesystem on `/mnt`. From that point on, if you `cd` to `/mnt`, it will go to the CIFS that you mounted there. When you unmount the CIFS, the original filesystem will be accessible again.

Do not mount your projects under `/mnt`. `/mnt` is meant for temporarily mounted filesystems, not for permanent work.